# Tree doesn't scroll on touch screen devices which don't have navigation keys

Tags: lwuit

I'm using LWUIT FileTree in my File browser but on touch screen mobile the tree doesn't scroll .It only scrolls if I use the navigation keys.How to make it scroll using touch?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this in [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) and it worked just fine. I don't think we made any major changes in this area. My only guess is that you might have mutated the tree outside of the EDT or placed it within a scrollable container that isn't appropriate for scrolling. E.g. border layout.

Make sure you place the tree in the center area of the border layout and set the form to scrollable false.